# Naming convention for syntactic sugar methods

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, syntactic-sugar

I'm build a library for generic reporting, Excel(using [Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.ch)), and most of the time I'll be writing things out on the last created worksheet (or active as I mostly refer to it).

So I'm wondering if there's a naming convention for methods that are mostly sugar to the normal/unsugared method.

For instance I saw a [blog post](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/060-issue-26-structural-design-patterns.html), scroll down to Composite, a while ago where the author used the #method for the sugared, and #method! when unsugared/manual.
Could this be said to be a normal way of doing things, or just an odd implementation?

What I'm thinking of doing now is:

```
add_row(data)  
add_row!(sheet, data)
```

This feels like a good fit to me, but is there a consensus on how these kinds of methods should be named?

**Edit**
I'm aware that the ! is used for "dangerous" methods and ? for query/boolean responses. Which is why I got curious whether the usage in Prawn (the blog post) could be said to be normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fair to say that your definitions:

```
add_row(data)  
add_row!(sheet, data)
```

are going to confuse Ruby users. There is a good number of naming conventions is the Ruby community that are considered like a de-facto standard for naming. For example, the *bang methods* are meant to modify the receiver, see [map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) and [map!](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map!/). Another convention is add the `?` as a suffix to methods that returns a boolean. See [all?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all?) or [any?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any?) for a reference.

Comment: I'm aware of the way !/? are used in general in Ruby, but is there some similar de-facto standard for this kind of naming or should I just stick with a default value for the parameter instead?

Comment: @gaqzi, if you don't want a different name I think default value for one of the arguments is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I used to see bang-methods as *more dangerous* version of a regular named method:

- [`Array#reverse!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21) that modifies array itself instead of returning new array with reversed order of elements.
- [`ActiveRecord::Base#save!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/save!) (from Rails) validates model and save it if it's valid. But unlike regular version that return `true` or `false` depending on whether the model was saved or not raises an exception if model is invalid.

I don't remember seeing bang-methods as *sugared* alternatives for regular methods. May be I'd give such methods their own distinct name other then just adding a bang to regular version name.

Answer (score 0):

Why have two separate methods? You could for example make the sheet an optional parameter, for example

```
def add_row(sheet = active_sheet, data)
  ...
end
```

default values don't have to just be static values - in this case it's calling the `active_sheet` method. If my memory is correct prior to ruby 1.9 you'd have to swap the parameters as optional parameters couldn't be followed by non optional ones.

I'd agree with other answers that `!` has rather different connotations to me.

Comment: I'd like to have them named differently to more easily distinguish between when it's trying to be smart and when it's just doing as it's told. I guess it doesn't really matter that much, though. I saw the construct in the blog post and got curious whether it was a general thing.